# Clarification when using the OVER clause

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

new to ORACLE 11g and I noticed the OVER clause seems pretty useful for some analytics. I'm having some issues understanding the syntax I believe even after looking at the ORACLE manual on the OVER clause.

I'm trying to get the cumulative amount for all gifts donated in chronological order. This is all from only one table, Donations which includes all the columns seen below in the query.

```
SELECT Donations.donationid, Donation.charity, Donation.giftdate, Donation.amount, SUM(Donation.amount)
OVER (ORDER BY Donations.amount) AS Total_Gift_Amount
FROM Donations.donations
ORDER BY Total_Gift_Amount DESC;
```

I thought I was on the right track but there is something I'm missing that's making my columns be out of scope. The error I receive is

```
Error at line 1: ORA-00904:"DONATION"."AMOUNT": invalid identifier (its the SUM(donations.donations))
```

Donations table includes: DonationID, Charity, Amount, GiftDate, DonorID

My main confusion is that when I DONT use the OVER clause I can get the result set no problem. However, when I try using the OVER I start to get lots of syntax errors and things of that nature. I want to learn how to use OVER properly though.

I know that error message usually is when you type an invalid column header or if it is out of scope. Why wouldn't it be able to see that Donations.amount is a valid column name? I could just be messing up the syntax of this new clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with analytical (window) functions.

The table is simply named Donation**s**, in plural, and one of the columns you're selecting is `Donation.amount`, with Donation, in singular. Slap on the missing "s" there and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the small typo I have fixed it and am no longer getting the error. That aside, would you say I am using the OVER clause properly? I'm not really sure if I'm getting the cumulative right for each gift

Comment: @ErikVorcov I'd order by `giftdate`, not the amount. Also, you consider a `partition by` clause - perhaps by the charity?

Comment: Yeah i was considering it but I'm not a fan of using syntax I don't fully understand !! Could you briefly explain partition? Does it group what you're operating on and then you can use the order by on it?

Comment: Ah i see, the computation would reset after each partition it goes through. hmm how might I apply that to this? set the partition to charity?

Comment: @ErikVorcov The `partition by` clause allow you to apply the function to a certain set of the data. So, e.g., `sum(donation.amount) over (partition by charity order by giftdate)` will generate an commutative sum over time, for each charity individually.

Comment: ok I see so it will apply whichever function, SUM, MAX, MIN, etc for the column you partitioned and then you can decide how you would like to order that result set. Thanks a ton for the clarification :)